# Wireguard on FreeBSD stopping on start

Tags: networking, freebsd

I'm somewhat new to FreeBSD and trying to setup Wireguard. I've setup Wireguard on a few different Linux and iOS/OS X based devices without issue, but running into an issue on FreeBSD (`12.1-release`), and hoping to get some help on where to look for troubleshooting.

On FreeBSD I did:

```
# pkg install wireguard
# cd /usr/local/etc/wireguard
# wg genkey > freebsd.private
# wg pubkey < freebsd.private > freebsd.public
# vim wg0.conf
```

My `wg0.conf` files looks like:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.33.3/32
PrivateKey = *******
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = ******
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0
Endpoint = *****:51820
```

On the peer I added the FreeBSD box public key:

```
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer <key> allowed-ips 192.168.33.3/32
```

And I can see it with `wg showconf wg0` along with the other configured peers that are up and talking.

Back on the FreeBSD box I went to start Wireguard as a service:

```
sysrc wireguard_enable="YES"
sysrc wireguard_interfaces="wg0"
service wireguard start
```

But it appears to immediately shutdown and `rm` the socket:

```
$ service wireguard start
[#] wireguard-go wg0
INFO: (wg0) 2020/01/18 08:43:28 Starting wireguard-go version 0.0.20191012
[#] wg setconf wg0 /tmp/tmp.TFUHebjI/sh-np.WiRXtI
[#] ifconfig wg0 inet 192.168.33.3/32 192.168.33.3 alias
[#] ifconfig wg0 mtu 1420
[#] ifconfig wg0 up
[#] route -q -n add -inet6 ::/128 -interface wg0
[#] rm -f /var/run/wireguard/wg0.sock
```

I don't see it under `ifconfig` (as expected), but I also don't see anything under `/var/logs` for wireguard or in `dmesg`. Anywhere else I can look for logs or get some more verbose output to help figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use a `/24` cidr block for my `Interface` address, and added the cidr for `ipv6` allowed ips.